# Global generation of a positive line bundle on a noncompact complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

One says that a holomorphic line bundle $L$ is **globally generated** by the sections $s_{0}, \ldots, s_{N}$ if $\operatorname{Bs}\left(L, s_{0}, \ldots, s_{N}\right)=\emptyset$, i.e. those sections have no common zero.

It is well known that  for a positive (=ample) line bundle $L$ on a **compact** complex manifold, $mL$ is globally generated for some big $m$.

Let $X$ be a **noncompact** complex manifold. Let $L$ be a **positive** (i.e. admits a smooth Hermitian metric with strictly positive curvature form) line bundle on $X$.

> **Question: Is $mL$  globally generated for some bi**g $m$?

> Clues:  Take $X:=\mathbb{C}^n$, $L=\mathcal{O}_X$, then the curvature of $(L, h_L:=e^{-|z|^2})$  is strictly positive. Now  a global section of $L$  is just a holomorphic function. It is easy to know that $f=z_1$ and $f=z_1-1$ have no common zero. That is to say, under this setting, the positive bundle $L$ is globally generated.

Comment: This should be easy, in the broad sense that bundles over non-compact things tend to have "more" sections than bundles over compact things. For instance, if the pair $(X,L)$ arises from restricting a positive line bundle on a compactification of $X$, then the same basis that globally generates the bundle over the compactification will generate the restricted bundle. But I am not well-versed enough in the differential side of things to say if one can extend $L$ in such a way that the metric also extends (while still being positive)....

Comment: That said, I'm probably overthinking; I would expect the non-compact case to be an ingredient in proving the compact case, as opposed to the argument going the other way that I have posited above.

Comment: @TabesBridges  Thank you for your good idea. But it seems difficult to go through.  Take the $\mathbb{P}^n=\mathbb{C}^n\cup \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ for example.  $|z|^2$ is the desired strictly psh function on $\mathbb{C}^n$ , but it cannot be extended to the $\mathbb{P}^n$ to be a strictly psh , by the reason that  the psh on a compact manifold must be a constant one.